# pythonのdeep learningのcsv読み込みでconvert error

Tags: python, pandas, 深層学習

今現在pythonのpandasでcsvを読み込ませ学習させようとしています。
そこで実行すると

```
ValueError:could not convert srtring to float'v -0.670323 0.017320 2.448769\nv -0.248426 0.066855 2.655411\nv -0.634120 0.159561 2.476978'
```

と出てしまい実行できません。
xの方にはcsvの列指定をし、yの方には３次元配列の画像データを２次元配列に変換し指定して入れています。

```
d_data_set = pd.read_csv("tes.csv", encoding="utf-8", dtype="object")

search_dir = './image'
f = np.array([data.imread('{}/{}'.format(search_dir, path)) for path in os.listdir(search_dir)])
f = f.reshape(len(f), -1).astype(np.float64)

x = f
y = df[:, "don"]
```

以下にcsvの内容を書きます。
このcsvには1行目のdonと書いてあるheaderを除くと800セルあり各セルには以下のような１行に各数値の間にスペースが入った数値が改行され3行ずつ入っています。

```
don
"v 0.310527 0.015296 0.505581
v 0.683512 -0.001598 0.216188
v 0.370806 0.149291 0.478181"
"v 0.313408 0.008205 0.505414
v 0.685073 -0.006196 0.214194
v 0.373934 0.142358 0.479367"
"v 0.304531 0.004002 0.505210
v 0.680174 -0.008961 0.219070
v 0.365913 0.138171 0.481338"
"v 0.297987 -0.006071 0.504920
v 0.676619 -0.010223 0.222481
v 0.357903 0.129184 0.483590"
"v 0.305034 -0.011075 0.504809
v 0.680596 -0.010772 0.218271
v 0.468077 0.124864 0.479119"
```

長すぎるため最初のdonを除く5セル分のデータを表示します。
私は最初のdonを除く800セルを800個分のデータとしてdeep learningで学習させたいのです。
回答お待ちしております。

以下に私の実行環境を書きます
windows10
pycharm 
python3.5

Comment: 深層学習については詳しくないので、あくまでCSVについて気になった点のコメントです。よく見る一般的なCSVは「1行(改行)ごと」がレコード、「カンマやタブ」区切りで列(=値)を指定するかと思いますが、質問のデータだと一つの値の中に改行が含まれていたりで、扱い辛いデータに見えます。Excel辺りから出力したものなのかなと思いますが、このデータフォーマットはpandasで許容されるものなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

以下の環境・コードで確認したところ、問題なくcsvファイルを読み込めました。

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Python 3.7.1
- pandas 0.23.4

load-csv.py

```python
import pandas as pd
d_data_set = pd.read_csv("tes.csv",  encoding="utf-8", dtype="object")
```

tes.csv

```csv
"v 0.310527 0.015296 0.505581
v 0.683512 -0.001598 0.216188
v 0.370806 0.149291 0.478181"
"v 0.313408 0.008205 0.505414
v 0.685073 -0.006196 0.214194
v 0.373934 0.142358 0.479367"
"v 0.304531 0.004002 0.505210
v 0.680174 -0.008961 0.219070
v 0.365913 0.138171 0.481338"
"v 0.297987 -0.006071 0.504920
v 0.676619 -0.010223 0.222481
v 0.357903 0.129184 0.483590"
"v 0.305034 -0.011075 0.504809
v 0.680596 -0.010772 0.218271
v 0.468077 0.124864 0.479119"
```

同様の環境で確認できてませんので、なんとも言えない部分もありますが、
pandasの`read_csv`関数のdelimiterオプションで区切り文字を指定してみてはどうでしょうか。

ref: [pandas.read_csv — pandas 0.23.4 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。質問のミスです。　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　読み込みは出来てるようですがその後のfloat型に変換する時にエラーが起きてるようでその事についての質問です。